# How to change --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period field in kube-controller-manager to 5sec in gke

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, horizontal-scaling

I am trying to set up an horizontal pod auto scaling in GKE. No proper documentation found to reduce the --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period to 5 sec using kube-controller-manager.

In the below link it says there is a possibility of changing the flags:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/

Is there any proper implementation steps to this?

Answer (score 16):

You are not able do this on GKE, EKS and other managed clusters.

In order to change/add flags in kube-controller-manager - you should have access to your `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/` directory on master node and be able to modify parameters in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml`.

GKE, EKS and other clusters manages only by their providers without getting you permissions to have access to master nodes.

But you can create cluster with [kubeadm init](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) and configure/change as you like.

Comment: Hi Mahesh, Welcome to StackOverflow. If the answer was helpful, it is a good practice to upvote/accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

you can stop your minikube cluster and start it with your extra configs ...

```
minikube start --extra-config 'controller-manager.horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period=5s'
```

for more details, you can go through https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/#modifying-kubernetes-defaults