# Add parameters to the EKS controller manager to enable ScaleUp behavoir

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, hpa

I have implemented **k8s HPA** on our EKS production cluster and it works fine. But we have a data science application in which the traffic increases quickly. So, Iooked into the below article on implementing the **behavoir: ScalUp** parameter to the controller manager.

https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-autoscaling/20190307-configurable-scale-velocity-for-hpa.md#story-1-scale-up-as-fast-as-possible

Something similar to this:

```
behavior:
  scaleUp:
    policies:
    - type: percent
      value: 900%
```

I have looked around, but not sure if modifying the controller manager is possible in EKS or not (we have version 1.17).

[Kubernetes unknown field "behavior"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045564/kubernetes-unknown-field-behavior)
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/176#issuecomment-462051548

Appreciate your support on this.

Regards,
Aly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EKS manages only by its providers without getting you permissions to have access to master nodes.

Note that Kubernetes `v1.18` adds support configurable scaling behavior -
[horizontal-pod-autoscale-upport-for-configurable-scaling-behavior](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-configurable-scaling-behavior).

So this will be possible once EKS supports `1.18`.

Take a look: [how-to-change-horizontal-pod-autoscaler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815094/how-to-change-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period-field-in-kube-controller-m).